# Populate #id with PHP/mySQL content with AJAX in Joomla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I have a jQuery function that gets data from a form and puts it as a string (for now) into an `#content`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').submit(function() {
        var results = $(this).serialize();
        var url = '<php? echo JURI::base(); ?>index.php?option=com_mls&task=ListData&' + results;
        $('#content').html(url);
        return false;
    });
});
```

So, I know how to build the query string from the form.

I have a task in my controller that runs a mySQL query string from the URL.

```
function ListData()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $sort = JRequest::getVar('sort');

        ...some other stuff...

    $query = [some big nasty thing]        

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $array = $db->loadRowList();

    return $array;
}
```

So I know how to query the mySQL DB and get an `array()`.

Then, I have a PHP script that pulls the array data into HTML format:

```
<?php 

    $array = $this->disparray;

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $mlsnum = $value['1'];
            ...some other data gets....
        echo '<div>' . $mlsnum . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Here's where I'm stuck.  I don't know how to get the URL query from jQuery to the controller task and then get the `array()` returned by that task into the PHP script which would build the HTML and then get AJAX/jQuery to put that data into `#content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action is going on in 3 steps.
First ajax call view.raw.php then you load/add/delete some data from model, and customize it as you want. Then you print it in JSON format - send it back to ajax, and then ajax put that into html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = '<php? echo JURI::base(); ?>index.php?option=com_mls&task=ListData&format=raw&' + results;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            if (json['output']) {
                $('#content').html(json['output']);
            }

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this will communicate with 
/com_mls/(default_view)/view.raw.php

in there, you should probably do something like

```
class mlsView_your_view... extends JView
{
    public function display($tpl = null) {

        $task = JRequest::getCmd('task', 0);
        // see what should we do now
        switch( $task ){
            case 'ListData':
                $data = $this->get_data();
            break;
        }

        // Get the document object.
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();

        // Set the MIME type for JSON output.
        $document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');

        // Change the suggested filename.
        //JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="resp.json"');

        // Output the JSON data.
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    function get_data() {

        // load model
        $model = $this->getModel('ajax');

        // get data from model
        $data = $model->getSomeData();

        if( is_null($data) ){
            return array( 'error' => 'missing data.');
        }

        $data['output'] = $model->prepareData($data);

        return array( $data );
    }
```

....etc....
}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a few questions...

`$document = JFactory::getDocument();` What document is it getting? What is this for?

`'redirect' => JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_mls', false )` What is this doing?  

Is this putting the raw array information in JSON format into the #content div?  I need it to pass through something that puts the data in the array into HTML code.  Where as, in the PHP script I have now, it gets individual values and places them where needed.

Comment: It`s the document you are creating.
Redirect is just something I use. I put url to array, and if I catch 'redirect' in response, I redirect user to new page.

You can do it 2 ways, put together html in php, OR catch it with json and generate html with javascript. It`s up to you, but important thing is that you get any response from the file.

Comment: in my example, in get_data method you would pull data (in model), and do what you need. then I would put it into an array (output) if it`s allright, or return an (error) if something`s wrong.

Comment: But then what happens to the data?  I need it to be parsed through a script to display it as needed.

Comment: I`m not following you now... 
You need to add **format=raw** to url, so it`s not loading entire template, but just that file.
If you know how to pull data, and know how to edit it, all you need is to put it in variable, json_encode it and spit it out. ajax will catch it.

Comment: So if I put in a `view` argument to the URL string, will it go to that view instead of default view?